# Parse-server get photo from postman (post-data)

Tags: parse-platform, postman, parse-server

I wanted to send photo from postman but i had error. How can i solve that?

```
{
    "error": "Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0"
}
```

My code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define(‘test’, async (req) => {
try {
const Test = Parse.Object.extend(‘Test’)
const obj = new Test()
const { photo } = req.params
let uploadedFile = await new Parse.File(
‘galleryFile’,
photo,
‘image/png’
)
obj.set(‘photo’, uploadedFile)
const data = await obj.save()
return data
} catch (error) {
throw error
}
})
```

[Postman error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49Pg6.png)

Comment: You don't need a cloud code function for this. First you need to upload the file using this endpoint: https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#uploading-files. Then you need to associate the file to an object using this endpoint: https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#associating-with-objects.

Comment: Actually, this is a test function. I will add beforeSaveFile function to other project. And the project which i want to  add beforeSaveFile function have cloud functions. So i have to use cloud function.

Comment: In this case I recommend you to test it by creating the beforeSaveFile function and sending the file using the first endpoint I sent you.